# Error prerendering server of a pie chart with D3.js in svg format

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, svg, d3.js

I'm using the library `D3.js` to draw a `pie chart`.

[This is the code which I'm testing](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/246b7d45e20be8680394)

To create the chart I use prerendering server side (NodeJs) using gulp, and the module npm `jsdom`, then save the HTML file. And it works.

```
// HTML SAVING  
// window is the jsdom obj
var innerHTML = window.document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var Parser = require('parse5').Parser,
    parser = new Parser(),
    dom = parser.parse(htmlString);
save(xmlserializer.serializeToString(dom)); // Save file
```

But I need to save in `SVG format`, then use these functions to convert HTML to XML for SVG.

```
    // SVG SAVING
   // window is the jsdom obj
       var body = window.document.querySelector("html");
       var svg = body.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
       var svg_xml = xmlserializer.serializeToString(body);
       save(vkbeautify.xml(svg_xml));// Save file
```

(npm modules: [vkbeautify](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkBeautify),[xmlserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlserializer) )

I have already done this with several graphics without any problems, except for the pie chart: HTML is perfect, but SVG is rendered badly.

Outputs:

[image: HTML output]
[image: SVG output]

What could be the cause?
How can I fix?

Comment: Is the code not wrong? You do nothing with the var svg and you serialize body to svg_xml

Comment: Can you post the SVG that you get as output? Two possibilities that that could explain this behavior are that there's a bug in whatever software you're using to view the SVG (chrome?) or, more likely, the d attribute in  `<path d="...">` gets mangled by the serializer. If it's the latter, than you should be able to see it by comparing the SVG output to the SVG in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/335LC/).

Comment: Thanks @meetamit, this is the SVG code in output file 
https://gist.github.com/andreaj8/382dbd9b9a924c310833

Answer (score 2):

It's a lower/upper case issue. Somewhere in your code you must be lowercasing the whole thing. As a result, a path descriptor in your output looks like this:

```
m6.123031769111886e-15,-100a100,100 0 1,1 -3.8285889215894375e-14,100l0,0z
```

whereas what you need for it to work properly is

```
M-95.10565162951534,-30.901699437494813A100,100 0 0,1 7.044813998280223e-14,-100L0,0Z
```

In SVG, there is a big difference between those two (lowercase means "relative to last position"; uppercase means "absolute coordinates).